# Ada complaining that I've added a volatile object in a function call to generic type when not volatile

Tags: ada, spark-ada

So I've got the following declaration:

```
      record
         String1 : String (1 .. 64);
         String2 : String (1 .. 64);
         Timestamp : Time;
         Int1 : Long_Long_Integer;
         String3 : Unbounded_String;
      end record;
```

And it's used in

```
package My_Vectors is new Vectors (Index_Type => Positive, Element_Type => Object);
```

which yields the compilation error:
`volatile object cannot act as actual in a call (SPARK RM 7.1.3(10))`

Now, `Clock` is volatile which is used. However I've removed the call to `Clock` and I still get the same result.

Also, I've tried replacing the `Object` type with a type of `Integer` and I don't have any complaints from the Ada compiler. Could someone explain this as I can't see how this is putting a volatile object into an actual anywhere please.

Just tried using the following record and I get the same result:

```
type My_Record is
      record
         A: Integer;
         B: Integer;
         C: String(1 .. 64);
      end record;
```

Comment: I'm no Spark expert, but Unbounded_String looks problematic here (it's an access type!) : can you use Bounded_String, or a discriminated record with a String(1..discriminant) instead?

Comment: Thanks; was trying that as you helpfully commented but didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Ada containers are not supported in SPARK (see [SPARK RM 14.8](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/spark2014/html/spark2014_rm/the-standard-library.html#containers-a-18)).
Use the SPARK compatible container `Ada.Containers.Formal_Vectors` instead (see also [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Ada-Containers-Formal_005fVectors-a-cofove-ads.html#Ada-Containers-Formal_005fVectors-a-cofove-ads) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/a-cofove.ads;h=5712e637b3538c75c462086567ce9625ea7e3599;hb=HEAD)).

Regarding the compiler error: the current implementation of `Ada.Containers.Vector` uses atomic operations to improve performance (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/a-conhel.adb;h=1a30b5305f01d3ad1d0418381b5a154187e78536;hb=HEAD#l107) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/a-conhel.ads;h=80ae98076a89e4277f1365f288761bbd6be2c41c;hb=HEAD#l43)). These atomic operations operate (in this case) on variables of type `System.Atomic_Counters.Atomic_Unsigned` (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/s-atocou.ads;h=b64f947bcc9b04c0bdd66c4e0893afc94af1d125;hb=HEAD#l75)). This type is declared as `Atomic` and therefore volatile (see [RM 8(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-C-6.html#p8)).